# Effect of hole conc while doping with donor

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

Recently i saw a lecture on YouTube there it said that the hole conc is affected by the donor atom and The fermi energy of hole changes due to doping... But since the donor impurity is immobile it cant be counted as a hole(Right?) then how it changes the conc of holes?

Comment: Cz hole concentration has dependency on fermi level. I suggest you to read this chapter. its there. https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The donor impurity atom is immobile. However, it creates a charge deficit in its region by giving a deep home for one otherwise mobile(ish) electron. That loss of an electron is what goes wandering around as a hole.